# token generate for forgot password

Tags: codeigniter

I create forgot password module.
MY Question: How to generate token for forgot password using codeigniter. i used codeignitor framework. below code

**Controller:**

```
class User extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->load->model('user_model');
        $this->load->library('session');
    }

 public function forgotpassword() {
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email Address', 'required|valid_emails');
        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
            $data = array(
                'page_title' => 'Forgot Password',
                'page_name' => 'user/forgotpassword'
            );
            $this->load->view('user_template', $data);
        } else {
            $result = $this->user_model->forgotpassword($_POST);
            if (!empty($result)) {
                echo '<h1 class="text-center">Thank You</h1>';
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Model:**

```
class User_model extends CI_Model {

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

 public function forgotpassword($data) {
        return $this->db->get_where('user', array('email' => $data['email']))->row_array();
    }
}
```

**View:**

```
<section class="container">
    <section class="login-form">
        <?php echo form_open('User/forgotpassword'); ?>
        <section>
            <h2><span style="color: red">For</span>The<span style="color: red">Love</span>Of<span style="color: red">Food</span>Trucks</h2>
        </section>

        <div class="text-danger">
            <?php echo validation_errors('<li>', '</li>'); ?>
        </div>
        <input type="hidden" name="token" value=" <?php echo sha1(date("Y/m/d h:i:sa")); ?>">
        <label>Email</label>
        <input type="text" name="email" id="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email Address"  value="<?php echo set_value('email'); ?>"required=""/>
        <br/>
        <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-danger">Submit</button>
        <?php echo form_close(); ?>
    </section>
</section>
```

Please Help me..................................................................................................

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to generate a token using PHP here is one of them:

```
$forgotten_code = sha1(uniqid(rand()));
```

Please note that this is just the answer to your question on '**how to generate the code**' but the process involving the recover of the password is more complicated then you might think.

I can advise you to use a class such as `ion auth 2` which is written to be used with `Codeigniter` and you can findit here:

https://github.com/benedmunds/CodeIgniter-Ion-Auth

This class will cover all the user authentication, login, password recovery and much more:

**You do not need to reinvent the weel**

By the way you have a typo here:

```
'Email Address', 'required|valid_emails'
```

You need to correct it like this:

```
'Email Address', 'required|valid_email'
```